# SQL: Join two tables with different type of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, join, casting

I have two tables with following columns:

Table 1:

```
OrderID    RetailerName    SKUs (varchar)    OrderDate
-------------------------------------------------------
123        ABC             1,2               2016-11-11
124        DEF             3,4               2016-11-12
```

Table 2:

```
SKU(int)          Product
--------------------------
1                 xx
2                 xy
3                 xz
4                 yx
```

Expected output:

```
OrderID   RetailerName   OrderDate   Product
--------------------------------------------
  123     ABC            2016-11-11  xx
  123     ABC            2016-11-11  xy
  124     DEF            2016-11-12  xz
  124     DEF            2016-11-12  yx
```

How do I join these two tables based on `SKU` i.e. how do I compare `SKUs` (varchar) column from table1 with `SKU` (int) column from table2?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple RDBMS, only tag the one you are *really* using.

Comment: As for your question, the solution is to fix your design. Don't store multiple values in a single column in a row; you should have multiple rows. Fix the design, and this problem doesn't exist. What you're doing here is breaking one of the basic rules of normal form.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the expected output, as well as tagging it with the [tag:rdbms] you're using?

Comment: @Mureinik I have added the expected output, I am using MySql DB please help me with this.

Comment: Still don't know what dbms you are using - Access, MySQL, SQLServer, Oracle? Can't directly JOIN these tables as designed. How many SKUs are allowed in the SKUs field? This is a comma separated values string?

Comment: the retailer is same for SKU 1,2 probably thats why it is given as "1,2" (varchar) but in table2 it is unique in this case how do we compare? @June7 I am using MySQL dbms

Comment: So how many SKUs could there be in that string - 2, 5, 100?

Comment: If the same retailer would have added another product say "xa" then probably there would have been "1,2,3" in there. As of now we have got only 2.

Comment: You're not obliged to use an RDBMS. If, for some reason, you can't normalise your data, then don't bother with an RDBMS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest normalizing the schema as [@Sodmond suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63661444/2422776). However, if this is not an option, you could use [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for the join condition - it will implicitly convert the int from `table2` to a character:

```sql
SELECT t1.OrderID, RetailerName, OrderDate, Product
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.sku, t1.skus) > 0
```

Comment: Find_In_Set is MySQL function. If dbms is Access it won't work.

Comment: @June7 OP is using MySQL.

Comment: Won’t you need to cast t2.sku first?

Comment: @reynoldsbj MySQL should implicitly handle the casting for you, although I guess it would be a better idea to explicitly perform the casting yourself and not trust the database here

Comment: I got the output using find_in_set() thanks to @Mureinik....yeah and also what Mureinik mentioned that Mysql implicitly handles casting is true, earlier when I tried to directly join using "=" it was implicitly coercing varchar to int and comparing only with the first val in varchar i.e. 1 among "1,2"

Answer (score 2):

You need to redesign your schema, Check how I recreate the table for you.

```
table1:

OrderID      RetailerName          SKUs(int)              OrderDate
123          ABC                   1                        2016-11-11
123          ABC                   2                        2016-11-11
124          DEF                   3                        2016-11-12
124          DEF                   3                        2016-11-12


table2:

SKU(int)          Product
1                 xx
2                 xy
3                 xz
4                 yx
```

Avoid storing multiple values in the SKU field, then you will be able to use the join query.

Comment: Except there should be tables Retailers, Products, Orders, OrderDetails. RetailerID would be saved as foreign key into Orders. OrderID and ProductID would be saved as foreign keys into OrderDetails. Basic many-to-many relationship for a retail sales database.

Comment: can't change the table design isn't there a way to convert the Varchar and compare it to int?

Comment: @AmerSufi you might be able to do that with the programming language you are using to talk to your database. Which language are you using?